# Mule Imap connector returns empty body content

Tags: email, mule, imap, mulesoft

Mule need to poll the bounce emails from office 365 to detect if it is a hard bounce or soft bounce .
When polling from imap connector mule  is returning only subject and headers but returning body as empty with mimeType =multipart/report .
Could you Please  is there any way we can parse the body in case of bounce mails using imap connector .

Comment: Is this Mule 3 or Mule 4? If Mule 4, which version of the connector?

Comment: mule 3 we are using

Comment: "The" body does not exist when there is a multipart/anything. There will be several parts. You need to find the right part, usually the second, and parse it.

Comment: is there any way how we can parse the multipart in mule and try to find the body in it .I tried with differrent transformer like email to string using encoding utf=8 but still doe not work